# Android maps v2 setMyLocationEnabled

Tags: android, maps

I know how to display the "show current location" button in a map fragment using this:

```
Map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Clicking on that button will center the map on the current position where the little blue circle is at at that moment.

But the problem is that the map shows the little blue circle since the activity starts even if the user don't click on it. And I don't want that because I am displaying the map with many markers and circles of different colors. One more displaying the current location is confusing. I just want to display the current location if the user clicks on that button.

Is there an easy what to Show the button to see the current location without displaying it yet?
Thanks